# Set the dates format so that it only displays the month and year - Android

Tags: android

I need to format a date to only MONTH and YEAR. Excluding the DAY, It is to be displayed in android.

Here is my code:

```
Date fechaDatePicker= new Date(txtRespTexto1.getYear()-1900,
txtRespTexto1.getMonth(),
txtRespTexto1.getDayOfMonth());
```

This is the code I have used to format the date:

```
static String DATE_FORMAT_PICKER = "yyy-MM";
static SimpleDateFormat sdfPicker = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_PICKER);
```

Here is format method:

```
sdfPicker.format(fechaDatePicker)));
```

Answer (score 4):

The format is not correct. It should be `yyyy-MM`

```
static String DATE_FORMAT_PICKER = "yyyy-MM";
```

Comment: Are you sure that isn't a typo?

Comment: before this lines I declare the datepicker.. final DatePicker txtRespTexto1 = new DatePicker(this);               LLayout.addView(txtRespTexto1);

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is possible to do that with the default android date picker. The easiest option is to use a custom date picker. Here is one -

- http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/

If you don't like that one, you could create your own date picker, here is a link on creating custom components

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html